# Prevent Null Value's return

Tags: linq-to-sql

How to Prevent Null Value's return in Linq

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific. When running which command? What are you trying to do that's not working?

Comment: I would say **a lot** more specific...

Comment: when the db server retrun the null value how can i prevent, I mean in T-Sql Ex:  Isnull(CustomerID,'') / Isnull (UnitPrice,0) but how do i use in linq to sql

Answer (score 0):

```
var noNulls = from someImaginaryItem in someImaginaryCollection
              where someImaginaryItem.SomeImaginaryNullableProperty != null
              select someImaginaryItem;
```